# Powershell to configure SQL Server Facets

Tags: sql-server, powershell

has anyone tried configuring SQL Server Facets using powershell... i tried with below code..and i am able to find out properties of the Facets but not getting idea on how to set values to these properties.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf') | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialNam('Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc') | Out-Null
$conn = New-Object Microsoft.SQlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlStoreConnection("server='Ramu-pc';Trusted_Connection=true")
$PolicyStore = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DMF.PolicyStore($conn)
$facets = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyStore]::Facets | Where {$_.Name -eq 'ISurfaceAreaFacet'} 
$facets | Format-Table –Auto
```

when i execute below command, i see different methods but i am not getting help on how to user those methods.
$Facets | gm

i need to configure below values in the above Facet:

- AdHocRemoteQueriesEnabled = True
- xp_cmdshell = true

Answer (score 0):

While it's not exactly using what you show but here's what I use.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
$server = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server' ('Ramu-pc')
$server.Configuration.AdHocDistributedQueriesEnabled.ConfigValue = 1
$server.Configuration.XPCmdShellEnabled.ConfigValue = 1
$server.Configuration.Alter()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automate with normal batch and sp_configure

I hope this helps someone find an answer while automating setting up facets, it would have saved me some time.

Replace `AdHocRemoteQueriesEnabled` for your answer instead of my working example below "remote access".

Similar to you I was looking for a way to automate, my case was RemoteAccessEnabled instead of installing the manager on any target
machine I wanted to setup as a master.  The above special keyword didn't even register in a search.

**sp_configure Transact-SQL statement:**

```
exec sp_configure "remote access", 1
```

also:

```
remote query timeout
remote proc trans
```

HTH someone